# Will I be able to bring this bent hook in an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, luggage, airport-security, western-europe

[image: The hook in question]

This hook used to be on a longline in commercial fishing. It had it bent to prevent the two points from getting stuck on anything in order to wear it around my neck. The two points *have not* been dulled.

What are my chances of it being allowed in my hand luggage as I travel by plane in Western Europe?

It has emotional value, so I do not want to lose it. At the same time, most of the time I travel without checked in luggage, so that would mean I have to leave it at home many times,

I could break skin with the sharper of the two, but so I could with the tip of a pen or pencil.

Comment: As a general rule: if in doubt leave it home. The security agents have the last say in what does and doesn't get past their checks.

Comment: Is it a necklace?

Comment: @Johns-305 it is indeed ( and more characters to go past the limit)

Comment: @JoErNanO I know... it's funny no one has created a business where they mail these items rejected by security to your final destination.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio There used to be a way to checkin sharp items and such last minute. I distinctively remember trying to pass security with a foldable knife, getting rejected, and being able to check in the knife in a cardboard box. Which might have even been provided by the airline. Alas this was in the late nineties.

Answer (score 5):

A tentative yes.

According to the [list of prohibited cabin items](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf) (linked to from [The European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/info_travellers_en)), we have:

> Objects with a sharp point or sharp edge (objects with a sharp point or sharp edge capable of being used to cause serious injury)

Your object is sharp and you could unbend it, but is it capable of serious injury?  Well, here's an example sharp object:

> knives with blades of more than 6 cm

So, according to the letter of the law, you can carry a 5cm long knife.  Logic follows that if some knives are okay, then a fish hook would be as well.  TSA uses the word "large" to describe fishing hooks that are not allowed.

Ultimately, it depends upon the person who checks you through.  You might even take it through many airports, and then one checker decides that it's not allowed.

Valuable items being rejected at security is common.  In fact, many airports have "mail it home" services, an in-house delivery system for you to send rejected items home.  If you want to bring the item with you, without fear of loosing it, check with each airport you're traveling through to see if they have such an option.